# Cordova plugin – class cannot be found

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I’m trying to write a plugin for cordova and I keep getting this error message when I try and interact with it on an android device.

Here is my Java code, which I have simplified.

```
package paypalhere;
//Lots of imports
public class paypalhereWrapper extends CordovaPlugin implements CardReaderConnectionListener, AuthenticationListener, TransactionController {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("coolMethod")) {
            String message = args.getString(0);
            this.coolMethod(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        else if (action.equals("IntPPSDK")) {
            String token = args.getString(0);
            this.IntPPSDK(token);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void coolMethod(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }

    private void IntPPSDK(String compositeAccessToken) {
        //stuff
    }

    //Stuff in here
}
```

Here is my Javascript interface wrapper

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

window.coolMethod = function (arg0, success, error) {
    console.log("coolMethod Called");
    exec(success,
         error,
         "paypalhere.paypalhereWrapper",
         "coolMethod",
         [arg0]);
};

window.IntPPSDK = function (token) {
    console.log("IntPPSDK Called");
    exec(function () {
            console.log("IntPPSDK Sucess");
         },
         function (x) {
            console.log("IntPPSDK Error - " + x.toString());
         },
         "paypalhere.paypalhereWrapper",
         "IntPPSDK",
         [token]);
}
```

And here is my plugin.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-paypal-here" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <name>cordova-plugin-paypal-here</name>
  <js-module name="paypalhere" src="www/paypalhere.js">
    <clobbers target="window.paypalhere" />
  </js-module>
  <platform name="android">
    <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
      <feature name="paypalhere">
        <param name="android-package" value="paypalhere" />
      </feature>
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml" />
    <source-file src="src/android/paypalhereWrapper.java" target-dir="src/paypalhere" />
    <source-file src="src/android/paypalhereCallbacks.java" target-dir="src/paypalhere" />
    <framework src="src/android/paypalhere.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
    <resource-file src="aar/PayPalHereSDK.aar" target="aar/PayPalHereSDK.aar" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="/*" target="config.xml">
      <feature name="cordova-plugin-paypal-here">
        <param name="ios-package" value="cordova-plugin-paypal-here" />
      </feature>
    </config-file>
    <source-file src="src/ios/cordova-plugin-paypal-here.m" />
  </platform>
</plugin>
```

Does anyone have any idea why would I be getting a class not found error? I have tried changing around some of the values in the plugin.xml file but nothing seems to work.

Comment: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343459/class-not-found-exception-using-custom-cordova-plugin). I think you're missing some paths in the declaration of the `<source-file>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you are declaring your plugin in `plugin.xml` then referring to it in the Javascript interface.

Change `plugin.xml` to:

```
<feature name="paypalhereWrapper" >
    <param name="android-package" value="paypalhere.paypalhereWrapper"/>
</feature>
```

And Javascript interface to:

```
window.coolMethod = function (arg0, success, error) {
    console.log("coolMethod Called");
    exec(success,
         error,
         "paypalhereWrapper",
         "coolMethod",
         [arg0]);
};
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, its working now! I couldn't find any documentation on the features section of the plugin.xml on the cordova reference page https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file